# Query from two tables by same condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am making a search page that will return results from two models, `AHotel` and `BHotel`. I would like to query both tables by the same paramater - ie, I would like all `AHotels` and all `BHotels` with a city attribute like "New York".

My search page should always show `AHotels` before `BHotels`. I would like an array returned with All the `AHotels` in nyc followed by the `BHotels` in nyc.

`AHotel.where("city ILIKE ?", "%#{city}%").or(BHotel.where("city ILIKE ?", "%#{city}%"))`

`AHotel.includes(:bhotel).where("ahotels.city ILIKE :search OR bhotels.city ILIKE :search", search: "new york").references(:bhotels)`

When I run 
`Hotel.where("city ILIKE ?", "New York").count`, I get 37.

And when I run 
`BHotel.where("city ILIKE ?", "New York").count`, I get 600.

But when I run either of the first two queries, I only get a count of 37. It seems to only be returning the `AHotels`.

How can I query from both tables by city? I don't want to run two separate queries as I am going to paginate through the results.

**Example AHotel Records**

```
{"id" => 1, "name"=>"Hyatt Place", "address"=>"Cox Rd", "state"=>"VA", "city"=>"nyc", "country"=>"US"} 


{"id" => 2, "name"=>"Hyatt Place", "address"=>"Cox Rd", "state"=>"VA", "city"=>"la", "country"=>"US"}
```

**Example BHotel Records**

```
{"id" => 1, "prop_name"=>"Marriott", "address"=>"Cox Rd", "state"=>"VA", "city"=>"nyc", "country"=>"US"}

{"id" => 2, "prop_name"=>"Hilton", "address"=>"Cox Rd", "state"=>"VA", "city"=>"denver", "country"=>"US"}
```

**What I would like returned**

An array with AHotel with ID=1, and BHotel with ID = 2, as these both have their city set to nyc.

`[{"id" => 1, "name"=>"Hyatt Place", "address"=>"Cox Rd", "state"=>"VA", "city"=>"nyc", "country"=>"US"}, {"id" => 1, "prop_name"=>"Marriott", "address"=>"Cox Rd", "state"=>"VA", "city"=>"nyc", "country"=>"US"}]`

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL? Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Providing us with example data and expected results also would help us helping you..

Comment: Can you use the link i used in mine first comment to make ascii based text table.. So we still do not know how your sure how your table looks like only that it maybe has a column with JSON in it?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Basically I have two completely separate tables. I want to query them both by city, and I want to do this in one query, because I need to paginate through the results. Both tables have a "city" attribute.

Comment: Well guessing time  `SELECT hotel_city_filter.* FROM (SELECT AHotel .* FROM AHotel WHERE AHotel.city = 'city' UNION ALL SELECT BHotel.* FROM BHotel WHERE BHotel.city = 'city') AS hotel_city_filter ORDER BY hotel_city_filter.id LIMIT ... `  Don't ask me how to do this in ruby because i don't know.   Only problem if you care is still `ORDER BY id` as that is not unique the results are still non deterministic (random) where there are ties so for id 1 you don't know for sure if Hyatt Place is first or Marriott when executed multiple times

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for your help! I'll look a bit more into Rails & Unions - you've helped me get one step closer. I think Union is the way to go.. completely forgot about those.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using STI ([Single Table Inheritance](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/single-table-inheritance)) to extend your `Hotel` table into typed classes `AHotel` and `BHotel`, you can query the `Hotel` table directly: `Hotel.where("citiy ILIKE :search", search: 'New York').order(:type, ...)`. This will return both AHotel's and BHotel's in the result.

If you actually have two physical tables in your database, you might want to use STI as a better design architecture that will enable that kind of querying.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! Unfortunately I have two separate tables and right now it's not possible to change the database architecture :(

Comment: Alright, then you have to use UNION (like another member already stated). But this kind of querying might become difficult to maintain and you might want to take a shot at STI one day. Additionally, you could use SQL Views to make querying easier on that "union" concern.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a raw sql query with union. will consider STI